# Use Hook to populate state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use Hook to populate state in below way.

```
class CreateService extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      serviceToUSe: []
    };
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.hostname == 'myhost') {
        this.setState({ serviceToUSe: require('../public/service/myhost.com.json') })
    } else {
      this.setState({ serviceToUSe: require('../public/service/default.json') })
    }
    });
  
}
```

I would like to populate `serviceToUSe` at the time of loading the component. But I am getting error.

Comment: Hooks are for **functional** components. You can't use them in class components

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Hooks in a class component. Hooks are to be used only in Functional Component

```js
const CreateService = () => {

  const [serviceToUse, setServiceToUse] = useState([])
   


  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.hostname == 'myhost') {
      setServiceToUse([require('../public/service/myhost.com.json'])
    } else {
      setServiceToUse([require('../public/service/default.json')])
    }
  }, []);
  
}
```

You syntax for hooks aren't correct either. Learn more about [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: Thanks @Pushkin for your reply. Will your `CreateService` call at the time loading component ?

Comment: By "call at the time of loading component", Do you mean, same component or another component. Are you planning to use it as Angular Service?

Comment: Thanks @Pushkin. I mean same component.  What can I use in Class Component instead of Hooks (useEffect) ? Thanks.

Comment: It will run at the time of loading. For class method, check out the lifecycle method. In this case you can use, `componentDidMount()`

Comment: `useEffect` hooks without a dependency run their callback upon ***every*** render. You should add an empty dependency array if it should run ***only once*** when the component mounts. Your syntax is also incorrect, you are missing the closing bracket for the effect callback and closing parenthesis for the `useEffect` function call. Functional components also have no `this`, or rather, `this` is simply undefined, so `this.setServiceToUse` will throw error.

Comment: @DrewReese, Thanks, I didn't notice `this`

Comment: Thanks @Pushkin. I was looking for lifecycle method.